# Export FireBase With gradle (RealTime DataBase)

Tags: java, firebase, gradle, firebase-realtime-database, jar

I want export my project of firebase to jar, and when I try use the jar, it doesn't work.

My build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: "java"

buildscript {
    ext.bukkit_version = "1.8.3-R0.1-SNAPSHOT"
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url "https://hub.spigotmc.org/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/"
    }
}

version = "0.1"
sourceCompatibility = "1.8"
targetCompatibility = "1.8"

configurations {
    shade
    compile.extendsFrom shade
}

dependencies {
    compile "org.bukkit:bukkit:$bukkit_version"
    shade 'com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:6.12.2'
}

jar {
    configurations.shade.each { dep ->
        from(project.zipTree(dep)) {
            exclude 'META-INF', 'META-INF/**'
        }
    }
}
```

I use this code to check what is the problem:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    System.out.println(1);
    FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
        .setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.fromStream(new FileInputStream(new File("../yourpixel/YourPixel/key.json"))))
        .setDatabaseUrl("https://yourpixel-22c2a.firebaseio.com/")
        .build();
    System.out.println(2);
    FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);
    System.out.println(3);
    CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("TEST").setValue("2", (databaseError, databaseReference) -> {
        System.out.println("Error:" + (databaseError == null ? "null" : databaseError.getMessage()));
        System.out.println("Reference:" + (databaseReference == null ? "null" : databaseReference.getPath()));
        latch.countDown();
    });
    System.out.println(4);
    latch.await();
    System.out.println(5);
}
```

When I run this inside my project, it works and the output is:

```
1
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
2
3
4
Error:null
Reference:/TEST
```

When I export my project to jar and use it to run the same main, it doesn't work. The output is:

```
1
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
2
3
4
```

And the program stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my problam. (I didn't said that i use intellij)
The problem was that the project that use the jar, had anoter jar.
i dragged FireBase.jar (the jar i made) to over craftbukkit (like in the picture) and it fixed it.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is a **very** bad idea in any program:

```
while (true);
```

This is called a tight loop, and it will completely tie up the CPU on the thread where you run this. And since the completion handler for `setValue` also needs to run on that thread, it is never able to execute.

To properly wait for the data to be written, you'll want to use semaphores to signal when the writing is done. For example, with a `CountdownLatch`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
        .setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.fromStream(new FileInputStream(new File("key.json"))))
        .setDatabaseUrl("https://yourpixel-22c2a.firebaseio.com/")
        .build();

    FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);
    CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);

    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("TEST").setValue("2", (databaseError, databaseReference) -> {
        latch.countDown();
    });

    latch.await();
}
```

Comment: "still not working" is unfortunately not very actionable here. What isn't working? Can you show your updated code?

Comment: `System.out.println(1);
  FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
   .setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.fromStream(new FileInputStream(new File("key.json"))))
   .setDatabaseUrl("https://yourpixel-22c2a.firebaseio.com/")
   .build();
  System.out.println(2);
  FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);
  System.out.println(3);
  CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);`

Comment: `FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("TEST").setValue("2", (databaseError, databaseReference) -> {
   System.out.println("Error:" + (databaseError == null ? "null" : databaseError.getMessage()));
   System.out.println("Reference:" + (databaseReference == null ? "null" : databaseReference.getPath()));
   latch.countDown();
  });
  System.out.println(4);
  latch.await();`

Comment: Yikes, don't post code like that in the comments please as it becomes largely unreadable. Click the edit button to add it to your question, then comment here to make me aware of the update.

Comment: I did it (i changed the code hat I use this code to check what is the problem)

Comment: Thanks. Now what happens when you run the code? It should no longer lock up your main thread. Does you completion handler now get called? Did you run it in a debugger with breakpoints on all your step log lines? Also: consider printing a `5` too after the `latch.await()`.

Comment: same resault, completion handler not called, and it don't print 5.

Comment: Hmm... I'm not sure why that would be, as this has certainly worked for others (and for me in the past, but it's been a while since I did JVM/non-Android work with  Firebase).